# What is the probability of a random walk hitting point x for the first time after n steps?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random, random-walk

For a random walk of probability $p$ for +1 and $q=1-p$ for -1, what is the probability of reaching point $x > 0$ for the first time after $n$ steps?

Here is my thought process:

For $x < n$, this is clearly impossible, so probability is 0.
For $x = n$, the probability is $p^x$.

For $x > n$, it's more tricky. In this case, $n$ must be greater than $x$ by an even number, otherwise it is impossible to reach $x$ for the first time after $n$ steps. Thus a condition is $(x - n) \,\, \mathrm{mod} \,\, 2 = 0$.

Now, the last step which the random walk takes must be the step to make the walker reach point $x$. Thus the probability is $p *\mathrm{P}(x - 1, n-1)$ where $\mathrm{P}(x - 1, n-1)$ is the probability that the random walker finishes at point $x-1$ after $n-1$ steps AND never goes past point $x-1$ during these $n-1$ steps.

I know how to calculate the probability that the walker finishes at point $x-1$ after $n-1$ steps because that's simple random walk, but I don't know how to include the AND condition. I suppose we would have to subtract all possible paths where the random walker goes past point $x-1$ in $n-1$ steps, but I don't know how to find all such possible paths for the general case either.

Comment: Please show your attempt at solving the problem

Comment: Oops! Is that a convention of posting questions? In any case, I've added my thought process.

Comment: Good to see! Yes, that is the convention. The primary reason (in my eyes) is that it makes it so much easier for an answerer to tailor their answer to suit your level of understanding, which will drastically increases the probability of an answer you can both understand and learn from. It also makes sure that we're not simply making your homework for you, without you actually learning something. Cheers!

Comment: See reflection principle here: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~breed/MATH671/lecture2corrected.pdf The result you need is Theorem 0.7 at page 3.